# Displaying action sheet when tableview cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Then I am trying to call action sheet when cell is tapped, and this is what I did

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "What do you like to do", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Ok button tapped")
        })

        let deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Skip", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Delete button tapped")
        })

    alertController.addAction(okButton)
}
```

When i am tapping cell, alert controller is not showing up. What am I missing?

Comment: A method can't access local variables declared in other methods. Why are you creating the alert controller in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: That is right, sorry I need to edit my question

Comment: @rmaddy please see the edited question

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: when i am tapping cell, alert controller is not showing up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there, make sure you add your `deleteButton`-action as well and present the `alertController` using `present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Sorry, should of course be `true` instead of yes, mixed up Swift and Objective-C in my head

Answer (score 4):

Your action sheet does not show, because you are not presenting it.

```
present(alertController, animated: true /** or false */, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Appreciate your response

Answer (score 3):

We create a function `didSelectContact`, and use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to handle selected Cell in tableview. If each cell tapped this action sheet will open.

```
func didSelectContact(){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Once", message: "What you want do with contact", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    let call = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in
    }
    let sms = UIAlertAction(title: "SMS", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in

    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(call)
    alert.addAction(sms)
    alert.addAction(cancel)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) {

    self.didSelectContact()
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done to help others understand.

Comment: we create a function that name is didselectContct then we use  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) to handle selected Cell in tableview then if each cell tapped this action sheet is opened